# Get Reference to the Presenter when calling 'presentModalViewController:animated:'

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

Is there some property so that I can reference the presenting view controller from the modal popup view controller. Seems like there should be one. `parentViewController` doesn't seem to be the correct view controller.

Comment: I should add that the 'presenting' view controller in this case is the master view controller in a UISplitViewController. I'm beginning to think that parentViewController is the proper property but the UISplitViewController is automatically making itself the 'presenter'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always:

1. Create my own subclass for my popup view controller.
2. Add a "parent" UIViewController variable to it
3. Set the "Parent" right affter I alloc/init it, and before I present it.
4. Reference my "parent" variable from my popup when I need it.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, was just thinking there should have been a more elegant solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For future visitors to this thread, as of iOS5, view controllers have a "presentingViewController" reference.